# How to add a Java ChangeListener to a method return

Tags: java, properties, javafx-8, changelistener

I've got a task-control GUI with an 'Abort' button which invokes some cancellation code (works fine).  However, I'd like to sync the button's disabled state to whether a task is running or not so the option is disabled if the task isn't running.  I can check the state of the task via its Boolean Future.isDone() method but I'd like to have JavaFX manage the state automatically via a bound property.  I can't figure out how to establish the binding, though, or set up a ChangeListener on a method.  Can anyone advise on how best to accomplish?

**Edit**:  I think this question ultimately distills down to *"How do I wrap Future.isDone() to make it an Observable?"*

Guidance very much appreciated.

Comment: Just take a look at the events provided by [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) (and maybe at the `state` property). They should be sufficient to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Thank you fabian.  I think you are correct.  My task class only implemented the Callable interface and did not extend Task as it should have.  Correcting that exposed the Override options I needed.  I'd still like to educate myself on what I think is correctly understanding how to implement the Observer pattern but you solved my immediate need.  Happy New Year and thank you much.

Comment: Dead end.  I'm using Futures to put a Callable into a ThreadPoolExecutor via `submit()`.  Code is correctly running in the background and arrives at completion.  But it seems `Future.isDone()` or `Future.get()` are the only way to glean info on execution progress -- the Task events `running()`, `succeeded()`, `cancelled()`, etc... are observed not to fire.  I think I'm back to my original need of some way to poll `isDone()` in such a manner that I can bind its state to GUI properties in a way that won't block or fail to update.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Task`. You can observe the `state` property to modify the `Button`'s disabled property:

```
private ExecutorService service;

@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    service.shutdownNow();
}

@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    // service = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 2, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10));
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button startButton = new Button("Start");

    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("task finished");
            return null;
        }

    };

    Button cancelButton = new Button("cancel");
    cancelButton.setOnAction(evt -> task.cancel());
    cancelButton.setDisable(true); // button disabled before submitting task

    startButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        startButton.setDisable(true);

        // cancel Button enabled until task is succeeded/failed/was cancelled
        cancelButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
            switch (task.getState()) {
                case CANCELLED:
                case FAILED:
                case SUCCEEDED:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }, task.stateProperty()));

        // simulate some work to be done by the service
        service.submit(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            System.out.println("runnable finished");
        });
        service.submit(task);
    });

    // show state as text
    Text text = new Text();
    text.textProperty().bind(task.stateProperty().asString());

    VBox root = new VBox(10, startButton, cancelButton, text);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you tremendously for the detailed reply and example.  I'm stuck with a design reliant on Futures, though, implemented in a base class that can operate without FX.  I'm trying to solve this problem in the derivative FX-enabled subclass.  I think that's the chief issue lies in that the Futures mechanism doesn't fire these Task state events.  I've got to figure out how to poll `isDone()` after the `submit()` without blocking the UI thread yet being on the thread so that button updates will render.  Usually when something is this difficult I later find I'm missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, or good enough. GUI controls bound to a SimpleBooleanProperty. Constructor kicks off a background thread Runnable that polls `isDone()` in an endless loop with half-second sleep and updates the bound SBP. Thank you again, fabian, for pointing me to a proper solution for future reference.